# blob: iframe not working in Cordova on Android

Tags: android, cordova, iframe, bloburls

I'm using Cordova 7.0.1, and trying to set the contents of an iframe using a generated `blob:` url, but the result is an empty iframe, and no console errors.

If I disable `blob:` urls in the content security policy, I get an error as I would expect.  So I'm fairly confident my problem is not the CSP.

I've also whitelisted `*` in **config.xml** to no avail:

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
```

Constructing a `data:` url works. Why doesn't `blob:`?

Ages ago, probably with Cordova 5, I had this working. Is this no longer permitted?  Is there a way to allow it again, or an alternative method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow blob scheme, we have to set the following in `config.xml`:

> **`<allow-navigation href="blob:*" />`**

More info on this is available on [Issue:CB9558](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9558) under official apache cordova issue tracker.